# How to order syslog data in csv by time

Tags: python, csv, networking, xlsx, syslog

I have syslog data in csv file and I am trying to sort this data by time.

Actually I am able to sort my csv data with the following code.

```
import csv
import sys, datetime, time
import re
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
import time

def XLSExport(Rows, SheetName, FileName):
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    wb = Workbook()

    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = SheetName
    # ws = wb.create_sheet(SheetName)
    for x in Rows:
        ws.append(x)

    wb.save(FileName)

ExcelExport = [["timestamp","source", "message"]]

rows = []
with open("All-Messages-search-result2.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row)
#print(header)
#print(rows)

excel_list = []

for row in rows:
    #print(row[0])
    row2 = row[0].split(";")
    #print(row2[0])
    #print(row2)
    excel_list.append(f"{row2[0]};{row2[1]};{row2[2]}")
    excel_list.sort()

# print(excel_list)

for sorted_ in excel_list:
    sorted2_ = sorted_.split(";")
    ExcelExport.append([sorted2_[0],sorted2_[1],sorted2_[2]])
    #print(sorted2_)

XLSExport(ExcelExport, "Messages-result2.xlsx", "Messages-result2.xlsx")

print("'Messages-result2.xlsx' file has been created. You may find sorted syslog files. Thanks for using this program.")
```

See the data before and after my code is run.

[image: Pre]

[image: Post]

However, the problem is that my code takes too much time to sort the excel if the excel has too many data such as more than 200k lines.

I think that the problem which makes the code slower is that my code appends each line as list and sort it by time. Then it creates new excel by using the list so that it takes too much time if the data has too many lines.

Is it possible to make the process faster?

Comment: 1) Why do `excel_list.sort()` after each row append? Why not pull it out of the `for` loop and run it once before you export to Excel? 2) Why the `for` in the first place? This: `excel_list.append(f"{row2[0]};{row2[1]};{row2[2]}")` looks to be rebuilding what you `split` here: `row2 = row[0].split(";")`. Why not just do: `rows.sort()`?

Comment: My 2) from above is not correct. I missed the `row[0]` part in `row[0].split(";")`.  Still I think you could get to what I was suggesting by doing `for row in csvreader: rows.append(row[0])` then do the `rows.sort()`.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your comment. I agree with your point 1. The "sort" should not be in my first for loop. 
In regards to the 2nd point, I just removed the excel_list that I created. I have edited my code by creating new excel after rows.sort(), using the sorted rows. I did create 2nd for loop to create new excel where sorted logs are kept. But it is still taking too much time to create new excel. Do you think it is expected to take more than 10 min.? Is it possible to make this more faster?

Comment: Please do not consider my above comment. It now takes 10 seconds. From my understanding, 2nd loop is not required. In addition, sorting should be outside of the for loop. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any option to accept the answer. Can you reply your answer with a post so that I can accept the answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions in my comments would be expressed in code as:

```
def XLSExport(Rows, SheetName, FileName):
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    wb = Workbook()

    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = SheetName
    for x in Rows:
        ws.append(x)

    wb.save(FileName)

ExcelExport = [["timestamp","source", "message"]]

rows = []

with open("All-Messages-search-result2.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreader)
    for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row[0])

rows.sort()

for sorted_ in rows:
    sorted2_ = sorted_.split(";")
    ExcelExport.append([sorted2_[0],sorted2_[1],sorted2_[2]])
    #print(sorted2_)

XLSExport(ExcelExport, "Messages-result2.xlsx", "Messages-result2.xlsx")
```

So eliminate this:

```
for row in rows:
    #print(row[0])
    row2 = row[0].split(";")
    #print(row2[0])
    #print(row2)
    excel_list.append(f"{row2[0]};{row2[1]};{row2[2]}")
    excel_list.sort()
```

As this:

```
for row in csvreader:
        rows.append(row[0])

rows.sort()
```

does the same thing, if I am following correctly. In the process you eliminate one `for` loop and do the `.sort()` once instead of for each iteration of the loop.